Proof of Conjecture on `Block-Orthogonalisation Always Reduces Trace'
I have a symmetric positive definite matrix, ${\bf D}\in\mathbb{R}^{NK\times NK}$, which is made up of $K$, $N\times N$, blocks:
\begin{equation}
{\bf D} = \begin{bmatrix}{\bf D_{11}} & {\bf D_{12}} & \dots \\{\bf D^T_{12}} & {\bf D_{22}} & \dots \\\vdots &\vdots & \ddots \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I take its inverse, ${\bf D}^{-1}$, which is similarly blocked with blocks $({\bf D}^{-1})_{ij}$. I want to show that the following trace, between two offset $(K-1)N\times (K-1)N$ submatrices of ${\bf D}$ and ${\bf D}^{-1}$:
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}\Bigg[\begin{bmatrix}{\bf D_{22}} & {\bf D_{23}} & \dots \\{\bf D_{23}^T} & {\bf D_{33}} & \dots \\\vdots &\vdots & \ddots \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}({\bf D}^{-1})_{11} & ({\bf D}^{-1})_{12} & \dots \\({\bf D}^{-1})^T_{12} & ({\bf D}^{-1})_{22} & \dots \\\vdots &\vdots & \ddots \end{bmatrix}\Bigg]
\end{equation}
Is strictly greater than a 'block-orthogonalised' version of it, that computes the same trace but between a block diagonal ${\bf D}$ and its inverse:
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}\Bigg[\begin{bmatrix}{\bf D_{22}} & {\bf 0} & \dots \\{\bf 0} & {\bf D_{33}} & \dots \\\vdots &\vdots & \ddots \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}{\bf D}^{-1}_{11} & {\bf0} & \dots \\{\bf 0} & {\bf D}^{-1}_{22} & \dots \\\vdots &\vdots & \ddots \end{bmatrix}\Bigg]
\end{equation}
I have numerical support that this is true, but cannot prove it. Can you?! (Or provide a counterexample?)
(My attempts so far: I can show it is true for $K=2$, and I wonder if proof by induction is an option?
You can also drop the blocks to make it easier, assume $N=1$, and then the goal is to show that dropping all the off-diagonal elements always reduces the shown trace.)

I found a numerical counter-example (to the block size 1 case)! It's not true.
Took so long to find because the counterexamples seem only to occur 'regularly' at dimension 4... which makes no sense to me, but there we go.
